# when blogging on wordpress. my blog destroys the template i created. how to avoid that?

Tags: wordpress

here is the site im talking about.
http://marillest.com/?d=1 (make sure to include the ?d=1)

i had set up a simple design with width specifications through css but when i start blogging and place large images within the area the entire design gets messed up. things go all over the place. how can i stop this? this website is for a client of mine and they dont know much css or anything and will be working throuhg design view in the wordpress blogging section. anyone know?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra `</div>` tag that's probably causing problems, according to W3C validation: [[Invalid] Markup Validation of marillest.com - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//marillest.com/%3Fd%3D1&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654)